# Surname blank on passport - Query about booking airline tickets

Tags: indian-citizens, tickets, bookings, turkish-airlines, alitalia

I want to book tickets for my parents' travel from India to Germany and back by Turkish Airlines and Alitalia . However, I have the following question :

On my father's passport, his full name (AAA BBB CCC) has been put under the "first name", while the field for "Surname" is blank. When I am booking the tickets, it does not let me leave the field for the surname as blank. In this case, is it ok if I put "CCC" in the surname field and keep "AAA BBB" in the first name ? In this way, the full name(First name followed by last name) will still read as "AAA BBB CCC" which on the passport.

I want to know if it is alright to book the tickets in this manner ?
I want to be completely sure about it because my parents would be undertaking such a long international flight alone for the first time and I do not want to put them through any problems at all.

I had written to both airlines 3 days back but there has been no response until now..

Comment: I suggest to tweet or DM to the respective airline. They'd definitely reply. E-mails won't get a reply.

Comment: what answer did you get? I am in the same position with my parents no last name. Please provide what you ended up
Doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely contact the airline. Putting LNU (Last Name Unknown) in the field can cause problems. Travelling could be a problem if the name on ticket doesn't match your passport.

As suggested in the comments:

> I suggest to tweet or DM to the respective airline. They'd definitely reply. E-mails won't get a reply.

You would want to check to make sure to be able to travel.

Comment: Or perhaps better yet, call them. I don't think an official support email is any less likely to get a response than a tweet or DM to their official Twitter account.

Comment: While I agree—many companies do not treat Twitter as an official support channel—the problem with calling is that many airlines don't actually train their front-line support well enough to be able to answer this correctly. The number of times I've heard of getting two different answers from two different customer service reps is astonishing.