# Will I be allowed to board if my surname on my passport doesn't match with the ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, denied-boarding, ok-to-board

I have two first names (for eg: Jas Singh ) and no surname in my passport. In my ticket from Delhi to Vancouver, the last name is Singh and first name is Jas. Will I be allowed to board the flight due to this mismatch?

It is a codeshare flight operated by Lufthansa. My ticket says Air Canada but it says operated by Lufthansa

Comment: I think this is not a mismatch of surname but other order of names. I think we have had questions like that before, but I am not familiar enough with the details of Indian names and other country airlines to know which is a duplicate and which just alike.

Comment: This was asked before at [Surname blank on passport - Query about booking airline tickets](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140962/surname-blank-on-passport-query-about-booking-airline-tickets). There's no good official answer so our best guess is to tweet the airline.

Comment: I asked the airline using twitter, this is what they replied. Hello XXX, for passengers not having a last name, the first name can be entered as last name. Please make sure, though, that both names are spelled correctly and match the passport.

Comment: So my second given name being last name is fine as long as it matches the passport.

Comment: After you have traveled, if this question is still open, can you please come back and post your experience as an answer?

Comment: I travelled and I had no problems at all. Your name just needs to match the passport. Doesnt matter forward or backwards, both first names or first name last name should be in the passport.